# Cache UIWebview Xamarin Ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have an application that calls a webview, this application is made on the Xamarin Android and Xamarin IOS.

In Webview android when I access the page the first time the page takes to load, but in the next request is very fast (even after closing and opening the application again), this is because I programmed for webview to keep the cache.

In the UIWebview (IOS) when I access the page the first time page it takes to load, but in the next request is very fast, however when I close the application and open again the first load is slow (as if when closing the application IOS cleaned the cache).

They would know how to help me keep the cache in UIWebView on xamarin IOS, and even when I close the application I have already made access on the page load quickly (as it works on android).

Comment: Because you  cleaned the cache when close the app.So when you open the web next time ,it will spend time loading the request again.

Comment: I did not clear the cache, I think this is being done automatically in the IOS Webview. That's the problem I'm having.

Comment: You can try downloading the HTML and saving it inside application directory. And then loading it next time from the local directory and ReDownloading new copy in background.

Comment: On Xamarin Android you have the method below to enable caching.
webApp.Settings.SetAppCacheEnabled (true);

There is something similar in IOS.